# 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Wizards' error in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017

I have been using SSIS for VS 2017 for about a month without troubles.

Suddenly, when I try to create a new SSIS project the following error dialog box appears:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Wizards' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried to uninstall SSIS package and to reinstall VS 2017 but the error still appears. Could you help me with it?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7d0e2381-e091-44bd-bc78-0b06bc6a6345/ssis-opening-error-in-vs-2012?forum=sqlintegrationservices : Though its highly volatile to touch registry. Better re-install sql server as well as SSDT both

Comment: thank you @PrabhatG. I have reinstalled SSDT and MS SQL server and it worked.

Comment: good to know...

Answer (score 33):

I was also getting the same error message when I tried to open `VS 2017 Integration Services` projects.  I fixed it by enabling the feature for Integration Services in `TOOLS >> Extensions and Updates >> Integration services >> Enable`.

Answer (score 8):

Actually the solution for me is simple. Some how the Integration Services is disabled. Re-enable it. Open your Visual Studio SSDT, go to **Tools >> Extension and Update** and Enable the "Microsoft Integration Services Projects".

Answer (score 6):

By doing this it worked for meTOOLS >> Extensions and Updates >> Integration services >> Enable.