# SSIS Data Profiling Task Editor return error codes

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to run SSIS tool "Data Profiling Task" with Visual Studio 2017

You can see the flow is running successfully

[image]

But when I click on "open profile viewer, this error code appears.

> Data Profile Viewer has encounter an unexpected error and has to be
> closed. The error messages are:  Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ScaleHelper, Version=15.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
> dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
> match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Is there any fix to this issue?

Comment: Could it be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310399/microsoft-datatransformationservices-wizards-error-in-vs-2017

Comment: I tried this without any sucess. I will re-install all visual studio, i guess only option left

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I encountered this problem in VS 2019.
I Added following lines to **DataProfileViewer.exe.config** in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity 
name="Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ScaleHelper" 
publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="15.0.0.0" newVersion="15.100.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

and the issue was solved. Please backup DataProfileViewer.exe.config before change.

Comment: What lines did you add?

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me as well, not sure how or why this assembly dependency is missing. VS needs to be re-written it is so bloated and full of bugs. I up-voted your answer, wish I could make it marked.

Answer (score 0):

**For Microsoft visual studio 2017,**

1. **Find the file "DataProfileViewer.exe.config".**  for me the location was "*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
   Studio\2017\SQL\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn*"

   **make sure to keep a copy of that file before change it**
2. add the following lines of code to it

```
   <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ScaleHelper" 
             publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="15.0.0.0" newVersion="15.100.0.0"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwIZ1.png)