# Open Profile Viewer error in Integration Services Project in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I'm facing an identical error to the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68549102/ssis-data-profiling-task-editor-return-error-codes). I have tried to add the following lines:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity 
name="Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.ScaleHelper" 
publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="15.0.0.0" newVersion="15.100.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

to DataProfileViewer.exe.config  as suggested. This was not successful for me. Can someone who has had the same error and successfully implemented the solution tell me where exactly in the DataProfileViewer.exe.config they placed the code shown previously? Perhaps they can add their entire file, that would be very helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: What are the SQL Server and Visual Studio versions you are using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own issue. I got the filepath wrong and was modifying a different
DataProfileViewer.exe.config  to the one shown, my mistake. I modified the correct one in (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn) and it is now working.

Please do not make the same mistake I did.